# Test method in Console c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I want to test a binary search in console app. I've populalated my array. I have no errors. Code runs... I'm not sure what lines of code I need to test this.

Here is my code..

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialise array
            int[] arr = { 800, 11, 50, 771, 649, 770, 240, 9 };
            int key = 0;
            Program.BinarySearchDisplay(arr, key);
        }
        //Binary Search Method
        public static object BinarySearchDisplay(int[] arr, int key)
        {
            int minNum = 0;
            int maxNum = arr.Length - 1;

            while (minNum <= maxNum)
            {
                int mid = (minNum + maxNum) / 2;
                if (key == arr[mid])
                {
                    return ++mid;
                }
                else if (key < arr[mid])
                {
                    maxNum = mid - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    minNum = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            return "None";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not sure how to call methods in console app," you would call it in the main method. Where is this `BinarySearchDisplay` method? in the same class as the Main method?

Comment: just do `ClassThatContainsTheFunc.BinarySearchDisplay(myArray, myKey)` within your main-function.

Comment: Anyway I'd suggest to *not* return different things from your function. Either return a number or a message. Alternativly use `out`-param.

Comment: @MongZhu Yeah the `BinarySearchDisplay` method is in the same class as my main method.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I tried that line of code you gave me, throws an error for `myArray` and `myKey` does not exist in current context. However I am using the `internal class Program`.

Comment: Post your entire code.

Comment: @Orion edited my post to show all my code as it is currently.

Comment: What are you expecting the line `Program.BinarySearchDisplay(arr, key);` to do? You're giving the method parameters that don't exist - you didn't initialize `arr` nor `key` anywhere in your code. The error you're getting explains it well.

Comment: Now that you solved some problems, can you edit your question so it asks about some specific troubles you still have?

Comment: @Orion yeah i'm having trouble understanding where to initialise when using a method inside a class. Like I said I'm looking for advice on best how to test this in `Visual Studio 2022` as a Console App. So I realise I have a few problems with it. But trying to figure out their fixes. **`I'M VERY NEW.`**  
And I'm testing this this way to better understand how it works, how it's coded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248928/discussion-between-gilli-and-orion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things of note here. Although technically correct, it is not a good idea to return values of different types from a function. C# being statically typed provides the opportunity to expect certain return types that are used to check the code doesn't contain errors at compile type.

A function needs to return a value, and so you need to assign this value to a variable. This is an example of how to do this for a function called `Fun()`

```
int x  = Fun(a,b,c);
```

Here is one way to achieve what you are trying to do. Have a function that returns a value if successful or flag when it does not succeed. Return a `bool` type indicating success, and include an `out` parameter that gets assigned a value before the function exits.

Notice that you store the results of the function in a variable `found` of type `bool` and then act accordingly using an `if(found)` statement

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Initialise array
        int[] arr = { 800, 11, 50, 771, 649, 770, 240, 9 };
        int key = 50;
        Console.WriteLine($"Array: {string.Join(",", arr)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {key}");

        // call the function an store the results in a variable
        bool found = BinarySearchDisplay(arr, key, out int index);

        if (found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found arr[{index}] = {arr[index]}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Binary Search Method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arr">The array of values.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key to search for.</param>
    /// <param name="index">The array index if key was found, -1 otherwise.</param>
    /// <returns>true if key found, false otherwise.</returns>
    public static bool BinarySearchDisplay(int[] arr, int key, out int index)
    {
        int minIndex = 0;
        int maxIndex = arr.Length - 1;
        index = -1;
        while (minIndex <= maxIndex)
        {
            index = (minIndex + maxIndex) / 2;
            if (key == arr[index])
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (key < arr[index])
            {
                maxIndex = index - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                minIndex = index + 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that `Program.BinarySearchDisplay()` is replaced by just `BinarySearchDisplay()`. This is because the function is within the same class `Program` and there is no need to fully qualify its name.

The result of the above code is

```text
Array: 800,11,50,771,649,770,240,9
Key: 50
Found arr[2] = 50
```

I think there was an error in the *op* code in `return ++mid;` as the next index value is returned. Maybe this was done because indexing is 0-based, and the *op* wanted a 1-based result. But mixing the two styles is dangerous and will lead to bugs.

This is a similar pattern to `bool int.TryParse(string, out int)` to convert a string to a number if possible, or return false otherwise.

```cs
if(int.TryParse("1150", out int x))
{
    // x holds the value 1150
}
```